# 2D arrays in NSPointerArray

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, calloc

I'm creating many 2D int and float C arrays and was going to assign their pointers to NSPointerArray. Everything is fine while I create and populate them with data, but when I do addPointer on array I get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. 
Q1-Why this is wrong?
Q2-What is the best approach providing access to many 2D arrays created with calloc?

```
- (NSPointerArray *)treeData{
   if (_treeData == nil) {
      _treeData = [[NSPointerArray alloc] init];
      int** VVD = createIntArray(3000,200); 
      [_treeData addPointer:VVD];
   }
  return _treeData; // addеd later to the post, exists in live code
}
```

For reference

```
int** createIntArray(int n, int m)
{    
  int i=0;
   int* values = calloc(m*n, sizeof(int));
   int** rows = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
   for ( i=0; i<n; ++i)
   {
       rows[i] = values + i*m;
   }
   return rows;
```

}

Comment: it's usually standard practice that the caller function is responsible for allocating and deallocating memory, not the function it is calling.

Comment: @AramKocharyan that is a totally wrong assumption. IMO. lazy getters allocate data all the time without the callee having to know this! and thats fine, in this case the **the naming tells him** that he has to later free the array! in dealloc or so

Comment: all arrays should stay and be available until the program quits. tree_data array with all 2D arrays in it should be available for other methods all the time.

Comment: @JanisJakaitis you're naming is fine :) I was too hasty there

Comment: @Daij-Djan that should be fine also, as long as the code which allocates and frees memory is in the same scope you could delegate it either way within reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the NSPointerArray has to be inited with the right options. by default he tries to RETAIN the pointers passed and as the int** is no NSObject, it crashes. **Instead, You have to tell the array to not touch the memory you add! init it with the opaque memory options**

you called just init which is equal to `initWithOptions: NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory`
you have call `initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int** createIntArray(int n, int m)
{
    int i=0;
    int* values = calloc(m*n, sizeof(int));
    int** rows = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for ( i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        rows[i] = values + i*m;
    }
    return rows;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        id _treeData = [[NSPointerArray alloc] initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory];
        int** VVD = createIntArray(3000,200);
        [_treeData addPointer:VVD];
    }

    NSLog(@"EOF");
}
```

Comment: _treeData = [[NSPointerArray alloc] initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory]; 
Still craches at  [_treeData addPointer:VVD]
;0x7fff8fd7d718:  jmpq   *104(%rax) EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: as I wrote "initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory"

Comment: @JanisJakaitis you don't deal with memory that can be treated as strong! 'Only' NSObjects can be retained and released. You deal with Opaque memory the runtime shouldnt touch

Comment: Thank you, it's not crashing anymore!